# Django filter __in multiple fields

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model for user timetable.

```
class Schedule(models.model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    day = models.SmallIntegerField()
    hour = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

I would like to select common time slots for two given users A and B.

Using this code:

```
user_schedule = models.Schedule.filter(user=user_a)
models.Schedule.filter(user=user_b).filter(day__in=user_schedule.values('day'),hour__in=user_schedule.values('hour'))
```

The results returned don't use both fields to select. Inspecting the query shows that the query is not doing what I want

```
WHERE ("profiles_schedule"."day" IN (SELECT U0."day" FROM "profiles_schedule" U0 WHERE U0."user_id" = 1) AND "profiles_schedule"."hour" IN (SELECT U0."hour" FROM "profiles_schedule" U0 WHERE U0."user_id" = 1)
```

I need it to do something like:

```
WHERE "profiles_schedule"."day", "profiles_schedule"."hour" IN (SELECT U0."day", U0."hour" FROM "profiles_schedule" U0 WHERE U0."user_id" = 1)
```

If I normalize the model further by creating a day/hour lookup table it would make the selection easy but I feel like it doesn't really make sense to try to normalize two SmallINT fields as I would be creating 2 columns of SmallINT for the IDs anyway.

Thanks!

Comment: What you here will get is a query that selects items where the day is one of the days where the other user can, and as hour one of the hours where an other user is free. But it is not per se the same hour on the *same* day and vice-versa.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you do not use a `DateTimeField`? This makes it more convenient to work with dates and time.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a way to build the query that requires both day + hour to be in the set

Comment: if you use a `DateTimeField`, you can simply use `TruncHour`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm not using DateTimeField because I was trying to store weekly recurring timetable instead of specific dates as user schedule is 99% similar weekly and I didn't want to store repeat data

Comment: Doesn't really make sense to use full DT field to store what is essentially 4 integers right? I could technically just pad the two numbers and store them as a single SmallIntegerField but I haven't fully thought about whether it might mess up anything.

Comment: The scope for messing up can be limited to database queries/ querysets by defining model properties `day`, `hour` to unpack those from a combined database table column (say) `day_hour`. Also after migrating (add the new column, delete `day` and `hour`) any queries made on the old field names will be invalid, so they'll become pretty obvious. If `day_hour` is `CharField`  ddhh you could filter `.startswith(day)` or `.endswith(hour)`.

Comment: @nigel222 That's a great idea I didn't consider when deciding between CharField and SmallIntField. Am I right that CharField(4) would cost roughly the same as two SmallIntergerFields but CharFields have slightly higher overhead when querying/sorting?

Comment: @Josh sorry can't help there. I've never troubled myself with questions of database efficiency. My apps are all intranet (small user count) and have tables with thousands of rows not millions.